# How to create boolean function from this set expression?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, boolean-algebra

I have the foolowing statement:

$$\bar{X_1}\cup(\bar{X_2}\setminus(X_3\cap\bar{X_1}))=\bar{X_2}\cup\bar{X_1}\cup X_3 \Leftrightarrow X_1 \cap X_2 \cap X_3= \emptyset,$$

so what I did was an introduction of shortcuts:

$$Z_A \equiv  X_1 \cap X_2 \cap X_3 $$
$$Z_B \equiv \bar{X_2}\cup\bar{X_1}\cup X_3$$
$$Z_c = \bar{X_1}\cup\bar{X_2}$$

The last one after some simolification

And applying boolean algebra rules I got:

$$Z_A= y_1 \wedge y_2 \wedge y_3$$
$$Z_B = \bar{y_2}\vee\bar{y_1}\vee y_3$$
$$Z_C = \bar{y_1}\vee\bar{y_2}$$

Finally I got something like:

$$Z_C = Z_B \Leftrightarrow Z_A = \emptyset$$

The only thing came to my mind:
$$F=\overline{y_1\vee y_2} = \overline{y_2\vee y_1}\vee y_3 \Leftrightarrow y_1\wedge y_2\wedge y_3 = 0$$

I feel my conversion/simplification is pretty wrong (I have to get simplified as much as possible boolean functiom from set statements above and then write up the truth table...)

Comment: Would you explain what you are trying to do?  What are the y's?  Where did they come from?  First simplify the left hand side of tge equation.  What do you get?

Comment: @WilliamElliot, my professor wants me to trsnsfer set exoression to the boolean one as about letters, x are for original set exoression While y is for the boolean one not to get confused

Comment: I have no idea what that vague stuff means.  Does he?  Give an example.